# Replace VLC plugin for Multicast (NPAPI Deprecated)

Tags: html, vlc, multicast, npapi

we were using the vlc plugin in Chrome to play a multicast stream (RTP Ipv6) but with the deprecation of NPAPI-Plugins we need an alternative. I was trying to search something about html5 video but nothing.

[NPAPI deprecation: developer guide](https://www.chromium.org/developers/npapi-deprecation)

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

RTP directly to the browser is not a solution I'd use today. The implementation effort to transform a number of RTP packets to Media Segments accepted by the Media Source Extension (MSE) is rather high and perhaps it's not even doable on all browsers (chrome.sockets seems to be a way to do it at least on Chrome browsers). Plugin development for more than a single browser is a nasty business as well. Don't go there!

I am not sure if it fits your requirements but here is what I'd do:

I would setup a process that converts RTP packets to MPEG-DASH packets on a server. Coincidentally I implemented a solution like that. You can find it on Github as [RTP2DASH](https://github.com/sannies/rtp2dash). The example receives multiple qualities of the same stream from ffmpeg but you don't need that - a single video stream from any RTP source should be enough as you can run MPEG-DASH with just a single video stream. Doing DASH seems like a big overhead in the beginning but the advantage is that there are players working on all browsers such as the [DASH-IF Reference Player](https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/) (I wouldn't use that one) or [Google's Shaka Player](https://github.com/google/shaka-player) (which is included in my example) already there.

[image: Architecture old vs. proposes]