# How to enable VLC plugin in chrome?

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, vlc

I am using a web application which supports VLC plugin to run the video streaming.
For this i have done some approach as follows :

```
1. Open Chrome and Open url : chrome://flags/#enable-npapi
2. Enable NPAPI
3. Restart the browser.
```

When i applied above 3 steps then it works fine but from some days chrome doesn't supports these

```
npapi plugins.
```

So, What is the solution for it so that i can run

```
vlc plugin
```

in chrome as my asp.net application is based on it.
Sorry for my bad English!

Answer (score 1):

From Chrome 45 and foward NPAPI is no longer supported it has been announced for a while now that they would do that by version 45, if VLC plugin relies on it then you might need to wait for an update on the plugin itself or move to other technologies.

The [NPAPI page](https://www.chromium.org/developers/npapi-deprecation) on Chromium.org lists some alternatives:

- HTML5 Media Elements
- WebRTC

In my opinion, the best thing to do would be to move to one of the newer technologies as Chromium team will probably not revert the depreciation of NPAPI. You could also warn your users to not update Chrome, but that would leave them open to vulnerabilities(Also, most users probably have auto-update enable so...).

Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635524/replace-vlc-plugin-for-multicast-npapi-deprecated) might be useful

Comment: Whether HTML5 is able to stream rtsp straming of live video?

Answer (score 1):

As NPAPI is no longer supported in Chrome, you need to use different web plugin for video streaming, that's all. Browse yourself, there are several good stable ones, I use VXG plugin.